# Escaping numeric tags when using hg log and revsets

Tags: mercurial

I am trying to do a rather simple hg log -r rev1::rev2 to get a list of changesets between two tags.

However in this particular repository the build server automatically creates tags for a build that are numeric such as 2.12.5.0 based on the software version. When I try do an hg log -r using these numeric tags I get a unknown revision '2.12.5.0' response from mercurial. I have tried escaping with quotes with no change. Is it possible to issue this command with numerical tags, it works just fine for non numerical tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the `tag` revset handles that:

```
hg log -r tag(2.12.5.0)::tag(2.12.5.2)
```

Comment: Thanks, I had tried this initially. I turns out our build server was creating a quoted numeric tag so instead of 2.12.5.0 it was tagging as "2.12.5.0", I updated the tags and build server and it works as expected. I didn't try figuring out how to escape the quotes as it was a quick and simple change that just works.

Comment: Good deal as long as you're able to update the build server have it put it word in there too.  Something like "build-2.12.5.0" is pretty common.

Answer (score 0):

Shortened version of Ry4an's revset (derived from `hg help revsets`)

`hg log -r "2.12.5.0::2.12.5.2"`